# Add PIPE as first byte in the first record

Tags: bash

File has the following records and how to append the PIPE in the first record as first byte using bash script.

```
2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
|2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
|2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
```

Expected Output as below.

```
|2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
|2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
|2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|
```

Comment: `sed 's/^/| /' filename`

Comment: Nice. I would select that as my answer. Just remove the space after the |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple GNU sed command,

```
sed '1s/^\(.*\)$/\|\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing

`2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594| |2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594| |2014-05-16T08:01:00-07:00|993820594|`

is in file1

Then adding a "|" to the beginning of the file is:

```
echo -ne '|' > f1 && cat file1 >> f1 &&  mv f1 file1
```